# "The Treaties" in article 50 of the Lisbon Treaty

Tags: european-union, law, article-50

Paragraph 3 of [article 50 of the Lisbon Treaty](http://www.lisbon-treaty.org/wcm/the-lisbon-treaty/treaty-on-european-union-and-comments/title-6-final-provisions/137-article-50.html) states the following (emphasis is mine):

> **The Treaties** shall cease to apply to the State in question from the date of entry into force of the withdrawal agreement or, failing that, two years after the notification referred to in paragraph 2, unless the European Council, in agreement with the Member State concerned, unanimously decides to extend this period.

My question is about the part in bold, what exactly does **the Treaties** refer to? The Lisbon Treaty website lists a few others, namely the Nice, Amsterdam, Maastricht treaties and the Single European Act. Does the paragraph above refer to those four, does it refer to all the European Union laws the leaving state is part of or does it refer to something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's detailed in [article 1](http://www.lisbon-treaty.org/wcm/the-lisbon-treaty/treaty-on-european-union-and-comments/title-1-common-provisions/3-article-1.html):

> The Union shall be founded on the present Treaty and on the Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union (hereinafter referred to as “the Treaties”). Those two Treaties shall have the same legal value. The Union shall replace and succeed the European Community.

So "the Treaties" is used in plural because the "Lisbon treaty" is two treaties actually; TFEU is the [Treaty of Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Rome).